# Why 14K views about concubines?

Tags: discussion

[How are concubines different than wives?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/5809/3555)

I notice that most of the questions on this site get a few hundred views but the question about how wives differ from concubines has 14,000 views. How might that have happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely at some point early in its life it made the [network “hot questions” list](http://stackexchange.com). The [algorithm for how these are selected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/272257) is affected by the score of the questions and answers and the age of the post. (New questions with upvoted answers are most likely to be included.) It is available at the link above. For reference:

```
(MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore
-------------------------------------------------
         MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^ 1.4
```

Comment: Interesting, Susan, thanks.

Comment: This is most likely accurate... The mod tools let you see where views are coming from, right?  How many residual views is this question getting from search engines?

Comment: @ThaddeusB, We can not see where the views for individual questions come from AFAIK. This was pure speculation, informed by my observations of more recent questions that get an unusual number of views in a short period of time.

Comment: @Susan So the site analytics only show total views and such, not per question?

Comment: @ThaddeusB [Correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77138/272257).  The closest to what you’re looking for would be to narrow the analytics down to a single day.

Comment: Small spiky mammals? What's not to love?  The cutaway scene to an 18th-century convict ship.
Captain: Aged, toothless, and bent old crone! 
Crone: 'Ow'd yer know me name? 
Captain: We wish to engage you as ship's cook and concubine. 
Crone: Oh yeah? What's a concubine then? 
Captain: It's a small, spiky mammal. 
Crone: [shakes head] No, that's a hedgehog. 
Captain: Oh. Well in that case, we wish to engage you as ship's cook and hedgehog.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because people are more interested in it than other things. We're not familiar with the societal role of a 'concubine' any more, and it is easily accessible, rather than our many questions on the subtleties of Greek or Hebrew grammar. And because in general, sex sells! It's no surprise that [the most viewed question](http://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/67922/most-viewed-questions) on Christianity.SE is [Clarification of what sexual immorality is?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11299/clarification-of-what-sexual-immorality-is)
2. It's really not that highly viewed, it's only the [64th most viewed question on this site](http://data.stackexchange.com/hermeneutics/query/67922/most-viewed-questions). It's less than one seventh the views of the top question! I should alter the query to show views/day, I wonder where this one would appear then.